# Node.js. Confused with non-blocking approach

Tags: node.js, callback, nonblocking

Ok, it seems that it's hard for me to start thinking.. um.. functional way.. or asynchronous way.

I am rather new to node.js, but I have many years of experience in c#, java, c++..

Image I have simple task. The idea of this task is that each line should be executed just after the previous line finishes (blocking operations). The normal approach in, let me say, c#. Also, (that was the reason of this post) let's imagine that we have one conditional line in our code. The pseudocode for this will be the following:

```
f = OpenFile("aaa.txt")
If f.ReadLine(1) == "bbb" // read the first line
    line = f.ReadLine(2)  // read the second line
else
    line = ReadLine(3)    // read the third line
DataBase.Insert(line)     // store the line in some database, lets say in mysql
DeleteFile(f)
```

Pretty simple. Now, as I understand, node.js uses non-blocking approach by adding callbacks to almost each function. By so, this simple task seems to become a nightmare to me. If I try to reproduce the code above, it will look like this:

```
OpenFile(f, function() {
    ReadLine(f, 1, function(line) {
        if line == "bbb" {
            ReadLine(f,2, function(line) {
                DataBase.Insert(line, function() {
                    DeleteFile(f);
                });
            });
        {
        else {
            ReadLine(f,3, function(line) {
                DataBase.Insert(line, function() { // the same again
                    DeleteFile(f);
                });
            });
        }
    });    

});
```

well, you see the point. In this example, if I need to be sure that reading the line will occur only after the file was successfully opened, I need to write "next line's logic" in a callback. And I should keep following writing "next line logic" only in "previous line callback). If I will not, I may run into situation when, for example, I will try to read the line of the file, that wasn't opened fully yet. Let me also note, that in my actual code, I do really use non-blocking functions, like, for example:

```
jsdom.env(..)
fs.exec(..)
```

Is my approach in code above correct? Or I miss something and my approach is totally wrong? I hope there's a better solution and approach.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you are right, it can be hard to change the way you think. And the code is not that easy to read. But Node can't separate your linear code in async tasks for you (that would be awesome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems to be correct, that's the way it works. And you are right, it is hard to find a stylish way to write async code.

One tool dealing with this is [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step), which allows you to define a sequence of functions acting as callbacks for each other:

```
Step(
  function(...) {
    OpenFile...
  },
  function(...) {
    ReadLine(f, 2, this);
  },
  function(err, line) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (line === "bbb")
      DataBase.Insert(line, this);
    else
      DataBase.Insert(line, this);
  },
  function(...) {
    DeleteFile...
  }
);
```

In Step `this` acts as callback and is replaced by the following function from the given sequence. It is also possible to trigger parallel tasks. Documentation is straight forward.

Probably you prefer this way.

---

**Or without additional tools:**

There is no need to use anonymous functions as callbacks. You can define a function and insert its name as callback, which allows you to eliminate code duplication without additional tools. Small draft:

```
OpenFile(f, function() {
    ReadLine(f, 1, function(line) {
        if line == "bbb" {
            ReadLine(f,2, insertIntoDatabaseAndDeleteFile);
        {
        else {
            ReadLine(f,3, insertIntoDatabaseAndDeleteFile);
        }
    });    

});

function insertIntoDatabaseAndDeleteFile(line, f) {
  DataBase.Insert(line, function() { 
      DeleteFile(f);
  });
}
```

Comment: well, it seems that its going to be twisty for my brain.. but it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

As a long-time C++ developer I can tell you:

a) Your code is o.k.
b) Your feelings are o.k. too.
c) It is getting better by time. In the meantime I am feeling really uncomfortably calling sync io-functions in C++

Here is another version of your code that gives you an impression, what you can do in JS:

```
OpenFile(f, function() {
    var myReadInsDel = function( f, n, callback ) {
        ReadLine(f,3, function( line ) {
            DataBase.Insert( line, function() {
                DeleteFile( f, callback );
            });
    });
    ReadLine(f, 1, function(line) {
        if line == "bbb" {
            myReadInsDel( f, 2 ); // you could provide also a callback here
        }
        else {
            myReadInsDel( f, 3 ); // you could provide also a callback here
        }
    });    
});
```